# Saving picture gives FileNotFoundException ()

Tags: android, file

I'm new to android camera API , there's a *PictureCallback* invoked in the code with :

```
     PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
          public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
             // Save the image JPEG data to the SD card
             FileOutputStream outStream = null;
             try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"\test.jpg";

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File Note Found", e);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception", e);
         }
      }
   };
```

The exception pointed out to this line :

```
outStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
```

Since I'm new to Android world, I don't know where's exactly this *Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()* points out.

The exception says :

> Java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0    est.jpg: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

But in my manifest :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

EDIT : I fixed the path to

`String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/test.jpg";`

But still gives me :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test.jpg: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses linux.  The path separator is `/` not `\`.  Also `\t` puts in a tab, if you wanted an actual `\` you need to use `\\t`

Comment: Hello this time the exception says `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Comment: Because you have not added permissions in AndroidManifest?

Comment: I have already looked before commenting; permissions to read and write internal and external storage

Comment: You also need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. then on kit Kat and layer you'll have problems because the sd card root is not writable, you'll need to put it somewhere that is

Comment: @GabeSechan, Invoked it on your answer, technically your "Comment" solved it first. Plus you "correct" my path

Answer (score 2):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test.jpg: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

you must have forgot to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I upvoted you, but I'll accept @GabeSechan answer. :)